# Composer Autoloader classmap custom file extensions

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, legacy-code

Legacy code...

**The Problem**

I have a bunch of legacy php libraries that needs to interop with new libraries. The previous developers named a lot of their php files with the extension `.class` ie (`FooBaz.class`). From my experimentation, composers classmap will only find files that have the `.php`, `.inc` or `.hh` (hhvm) extensions.

In my searching I have failed to come up with any suitable solution.

**The Question**

Is there any non-invasive (modifying composer) solution to including custom extensions (like `.class`) in composers classmap autoload mapping?

Comment: You can also use a `classmap` where you define each of your legacy files https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md

Comment: @cmorrissey unfortunately composer ignores this if the legacy file is not named with the standard set of extensions.

Comment: even if you do something like this `"classmap": ["Foo.class", "Bar.class", "Foo/Bar.class"]` ?

Comment: Your going to want to look at the two lines of code on GitHub marked in the answer in the duplicate link.  Also what is your aversion to renaming the files with `.php`?

Comment: I have no aversion to that idea, but almost everyone else on my team is against it.

Comment: You can always name files like `Foo.class.php`